# Finding gradient of an optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-pde, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to find the gradient of the following optimization problem and then add to objective, but I got some trouble in computing. Could you please help me?

Assume that we have an optimization problem with the objective
$$ \min_{w} \sum_{j}^{n}\sum_{i}^{n_t} \left( \hat{T}_j(t_i) -
  T(t_i, w) \right)^2 + c . \| w \|_1 $$
where $w \in [ 0, 1 ]$ and $c$ is a constant. $\hat{T}_j(t_i)$ and $T(t_i, w)$ are computed using heat equation with initial value:
$$\begin{array}{rlll}
    T_t(t,x) + L_w . T(t,x) & = & F(t,x) , \\
%    T(0,t) & = & T(1,t) = 0 &  \\
    T(x,0) & = & T_0 .
  \end{array}$$
$F(t,x)$ is given and $L_w$ is the weighted Laplacian of a graph $G=(V,E)$ and $$L_w(G):= \sum_{ij \in E} w_{ij} E_{ij}$$
It should be added that $\hat{T}_j(t_i)$ is obtained from above equations by fixing an arbitrary $w$, but for $T(t_i, w)$ is changing in each time step.

Comment: You optimize over a binary variable (which seems to be a binary matrix, right?)? And you want the gradient of the objective with respect to this binary variable $w$? Better relax to $w_{ij}\in[0,1]$ or so. Also: What do you mean by "but for $T(t_i,w)$ is changing in each time step"?

Comment: @Dirk you're right. the relaxed variable $w$ would be better. I have modified my question, now.
well because in each step $w$ would be changed to a new one then from the equation the heat $T(t_i, w)$ would change, too. Maybe if I say that $T(t_i, w)$ is updating in each step, rather would be better.